# How to add dropdown in multiple columns in an excel sheet using python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am unable to add dropdown in excel sheet. I have the follow code but it is giving error

```
def formatContent(output_path):
  
    # based on above generated file, below actions is for adding data validity and adjust the formatting
    from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    from openpyxl.styles import Font, PatternFill, Alignment
    # import os
    
    # nowTime=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  
    formula = '"Data Source Error,CRA Rotation,Methodology ,Rating_Level_Issues,NID Process,Pricing,Size,Local / Domestic Issuance,Confidential Rating,Client Choice,No response"'
    formula_1 = '"Juyong Baek,Kanchan  Arora,Tommy Kuang,Naoya Tsuruoka,Denis OSullivan,Eva Wu,Scarlett Lan,Xiao  Xiao,Kelly Lim,Sherman Chung,Benjamin  Fleming,Anthony  Foo,Peony Chan,Ray Mau,Genki Ikeda,Vicky Shen,Dongsheng Hong,John Birch,Valerie Lee,Yookyung Lee,Lee Wen En,Hoe Darren,Tom Ledgerwood"'
    wkbk = load_workbook(filename = output_path, data_only=False)
    
    for i in range(0,1):
        code = DataValidation(type="list",formula1=formula,allow_blank=True)
        code.error = 'No such item in the dropdown'
        code.errorTitle = 'Invalid Input'
        code.prompt = 'Please select an item from the dropdown'
        code.promptTitle = 'Select from the dropdown'
        wkbk[wkbk.sheetnames[i]].add_data_validation(code)
        code.add('AC2:AC3000')
        
        code_1 = DataValidation(type="list",formula1=formula_1,allow_blank=True)
        code_1.error = 'No such item in the dropdown'
        code_1.errorTitle = 'Invalid Input'
        code_1.prompt = 'Please select an item from the dropdown'
        code_1.promptTitle = 'Select from the dropdown'
        wkbk[wkbk.sheetnames[i]].add_data_validation(code_1)
        code_1.add('AF2:AF3000')
        
        # ft=Font(name="Calibli",size=7)
        ft=Font(name="Calibri",size=8)
        fill=PatternFill(start_color='CCCCCC',end_color='CCCCCC',fill_type="solid")
        align=Alignment(horizontal="center",vertical="center",wrap_text=True)
        row_nub=wkbk[wkbk.sheetnames[i]].max_row
        for j in range(1,row_nub+1):
            # MPS[MPS.sheetnames[i]].row_dimensions[j].height=25
            wkbk[wkbk.sheetnames[i]].row_dimensions[j]
            for k in range(1,34):
                wkbk[wkbk.sheetnames[i]].cell(row=j,column=k).font=ft
                wkbk[wkbk.sheetnames[i]].cell(row=1,column=k).font=ft
                wkbk[wkbk.sheetnames[i]].cell(row=1,column=k).fill=fill
                wkbk[wkbk.sheetnames[i]].cell(row=1,column=k).alignment=align
  
    wkbk.save(output_path)
    print("Process Completed.")
```

formula and formula_1 is the list which needs to be added as a dropdown option of column AC and AF in the excel. Although the above code is working, but when I open the output excel, there's no dropdown in any of the column

Any suggestion

Comment: I think this is probably related to https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1770 What happens if you set `showDropDown=True`?

Comment: @CharlieClark When I add just one dropdown (of formula in column AC) then I am able to see the dropdown but when I add another dropdown (of formula_1 in column AF) then the dropdown goes in both the column. So, in short, I am unable to apply dropdown in multiple columns (just able to apple dropdown in a single column).

Comment: Your problem is you are exceeding the length of the formula string in **formula_1**. It cannot exceed 255 characters. Even removing any extraneous spaces in that string you will be at least two names over the limit, in fact if you trim all unnecessary spaces you can just fit all the names except the last two.

Comment: May I suggest you enter the names into the sheet and use a range as the formula instead.